# RNN Word embedding: How important is sorting word representation vocabulary?

Tags: recurrent-neural-network, word-embedding, encoder-decoder

I am building an encoder-decoder translation model. Words are represented as an array with corresponding one-hot numbering that is the input for the encoder.

```
aaa 00001
aab 00010
aba 00100
```

I have noticed in various sources that word representations are usually sorted alphabetically. In terms of precision and training time, does it produce better results than unsorted?